# Cakephp Form helper not working in jQuery append

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to put a div into append but I am always getting `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

My div look like

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
     <div class='form-group'>
          <?= $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users,'class'=>'form-control']);?>
      </div>
     <div class='form-group'>
           <?= $this->Form->control('phone_number',['class'=>'form-control']); ?>
     </div>              
</div>
```

I have tried in append like below

```
$('#cform').append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><?= $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users,'class'=>'form-control']);?></div><div class='form-group'><?= $this->Form->control('phone_number',['class'=>'form-control']); ?></div></div>");
```

I am not getting any syntax error here, How can I solve this ?

Comment: You are embedding PHP code inside of a JS string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use back tick `

```
$('#cform').append(`<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><?= $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users,'class'=>'form-control']);?></div><div class='form-group'><?= $this->Form->control('phone_number',['class'=>'form-control']); ?></div></div>`);
```

Back tick may be not support in IE, So you can use "\" before space

Example :

```
<div class="form-group">\
  <?= $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users,'class'=>'form-control']);?>\
</div>\
<div class="form-group">\
<?= $this->Form->control('phone_number',['class'=>'form-control']); ?>\
</div>\
```